# Fetch human-readable value of a Django Form field

Tags: django, forms

I have the below code in my forms.py:

```
class MultiFilterForm(forms.Form):

    review_choice =(('gte', 'Reviews >=',), 
                    ('exact', 'Reviews =',), 
                    ('lte', 'Reviews <=',))
    
    reviewsign = forms.ChoiceField(choices = review_choice, required = False,
                                    widget = forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'reviewSign','class': 'form-control',}))
```

What I need to do, is in my template, display the 2nd value in each tuple. I can write `{{form.review.value}}`  and that'll access the 1st value in each tuple like `gte` or `exact` or `lte`, but how can I access the human readable form in the 2nd position in each tuple?

To clarify, I've already read up on the `get_FOO_display()`  for model fields. But again, this is for a form field to be displayed in the template, not the model field. Any pointers, please let me know! I'm at my wits end. Thanks

Comment: I go through your code, it already shows 2nd value of the tuple
see ```https://prnt.sc/1z2s8xz```

Comment: See the problem is that is a dropdown. I need to access that 2nd value in 'label' form.